# Using True Type Fonts (ttf)

Tags: css

I have found some nice True-Type fonts on the web, and I would like to use them for specific roles in a specific theme of my WP blog (e.g., `H2` or post titles).

How do I change the theme to use the fonts for these roles?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this be done by using plugins?

Like this:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-google-fonts/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/font/

Answer (score 0):

One, you could edit all the instances of the title in the theme files. You can use `current_user_can` to differentiate between roles. [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)

You may also be able to use a filter instead of having to edit all the theme files.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse40503_changetitlefontonrole');
function wpse40503_changetitlefontonrole($title) {
  if(current_user_can('change this to your role')) {
    if( $title == $post->post_title and !is_page() ) {
      $title = '<span class="specificrolefont">'.$title.'</span>';
    }
  }
  return $title;
}
?>
```

And then do not forget to add CSS styles for the font.